# How to capture the scroll position at the end of the div element?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to capture scroll position at the end of the specific div element. But I couldn't fix that. What should I do ? Could you please help me about this situation? Here is the following basic application link regarding my issue.
Thanks for your help and suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Here is the basic application link regarding my issue: https://codepen.io/ilyokon/pen/ZERxeKj

Comment: Maybe you looking for [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Intersection Observer for what you want to do. So you could do something like this:

```
var observer = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries) {
    if(entries[0].isIntersecting === true)
        alert('hello');
}, { threshold: [1] });

observer.observe(document.querySelector(".launch-alert"));
```

Simply add a div with the class launch-alert at the end or your content and when it will be fully visible your alert will be trigger.

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I would like to do scroll to load. So, my content div's height value changes with number of product count. I think I couldn't define a spesific value for the scroll position. Am I right?

Comment: Indeed, sorry I thought the height was fixed